# Business Desktop Remix Download

Tags: 14.04

I heared about Ubuntu Business Desktop Remix that is targeted for business deployments.

Is it freely available as all Ubuntu flavors? and from where can I download it ?

P.S : I already checked http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.1/ but couldn't find it !

Answer (score 4):

That was the term used back in 2012. Nowadays it is called "Ubuntu advantage". It is not a download but a support agreement for larger companies. If you are asking this as a single user you are suppose to get support from the community. A 1 year support costs about [440 British Pounds](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=658) and you will need to contact Canonical. Below several snippets from the Ubuntu website with links to the pages and a link to the contact form.

---

> **Systems management and support**
>
> Ubuntu Advantage is the professional support package from Canonical, with Landscape, a systems management tool, built for running large-scale Ubuntu deployments on desktop, server or cloud.

---

> **Ubuntu Advantage: what’s included?**
>
> - Systems management: Landscape
>
> With the Landscape systems management tool, you can automate updates and manage physical, virtual and cloud-based systems from a single interface. It's easy to set up, easy to use and requires no special hardware. It features:
>
> - Management at scale
> - Deploy or rollback security updates
> - Compliance reports
> - Role-based access
> - Informative monitoring
>
> [Learn more](http://www.ubuntu.com/management/landscape-features)
>
> Try Landscape for free for 30 days
>
> For a limited period, you can try Landscape without subscribing to Ubuntu Advantage. Register for your 30 day free trial, to see the features for yourself. [Login into landscape](https://login.ubuntu.com/HRvruJsFhR4goUps/+decide) as a new user.

---

> **Contact Canonical**
>
> Considering Ubuntu for your business? Just fill in the form below and a member of our team will be in touch within two working days.
>
> [You need to fill in this form](http://www.ubuntu.com/management/contact-us).

---

Regarding comments:

> this ISO available for download, or is it only available for subscribed customers ?

There is no ISO.

> regarding the link mentioned "[introducing ubuntu business desktop remix desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/content/introducing-ubuntu-business-desktop-remix-desktop-enterprise)"

This seems a page from 2012 to me. If you click the ["enterprise"](http://www.ubuntu.com/category/audience/enterprise-0) link below it you go to some more older pages all referring 2012.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind for your reply; I'm already aware of Ubuntu Advantage. but the Desktop Remix I meant isn't a program. it is a downloadable ISO that is stripped out of backages that is unnecessary for enterprise deployments and customized with extra beneficial packages (Likewise open and domain join for example).

My question is; is this ISO available for download, or is it only available for subscribed customers ?

Comment: Please check http://www.ubuntu.com/content/introducing-ubuntu-business-desktop-remix-desktop-enterprise as well

Comment: If there was such a thing it would be on our download page ;) We have a  desktop and a server version. Nothing more. If you refer to this: http://www.ubuntu.com/content/introducing-ubuntu-business-desktop-remix-desktop-enterprise It is a page from 2012 and will get you to the text I posted in the answer. Nowadays it is called "Ubuntu advantage" and is a cloud support solution. If you click "enterprise" below your link you will get pages from 2012: http://www.ubuntu.com/category/audience/enterprise-0 @Ahmadgeo

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the confusion and possible misunderstanding in the past answer and comments; and upon checking more deeply and thanks to @Rinzwind for the heads-up :)

Ubuntu Desktop Remix was indeed available for Free Download from http://blog.canonical.com/2012/05/10/the-new-business-desktop-remix-is-out-now/ and was based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

from above link I quote;

"Designed for corporate and government organisations evaluating Ubuntu for their desktop infrastructure, the Business Desktop Remix is a simple base image that can be deployed into your corporate environment or used as a starting point for further customisation.
To save time in deployment, we’ve removed games, social networking programs, file sharing apps and technical tools. In their place, you’ll find software more appropriate for a corporate environment, including VMware View, the Adobe Flash Plugin and the OpenJDK 6 Java runtime environment. Ubuntu Business Desktop Remix provides full language support in both 32 and 64-bit builds, just like the standard Ubuntu. Users also benefit from the great new productivity features introduced in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, including built-in support for Microsoft Windows RDP 7.1 and the Microsoft Visio diagram importer in LibreOffice Draw."

Also; Register now to download Ubuntu Business Desktop Remix – and start evaluating what Canonical can do for you today.

Finally; this is a pretty good concept and I wish Canonical avail it once again as an Ubuntu flavor in addition to Server and regular Desktop Downloads.